# Android resource linking failed. How to solve errors in ic_launcher_foreground.xml file?

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, android-launcher

I have updated my build.gradle App file, SDK-versions and after that I am encountering this error in my ic_launcher_foreground file.

I have tried:
clean/re-build,
invalidate caches/restart,
deleting project and installing again.
Nothing works.

[Debug Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbbp8.png)

[Build.gradle App file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X56r7.png)

[ic_launcher_foreground.xml file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78JcZ.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text. That said, it looks like your `compileSdkVersion` is too low. It has to be at least 24 for those attributes, I believe, which is specifically why you're getting those errors. However, you should always use the latest version available for `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: Please can you elaborate what is the link of compile sdk version to ic_launcher_file? can you suggest me any link for that.

Comment: For which attributes you see, that my compile sdk version should be 24?

Comment: All of the ones mentioned in the `error: attribute android:* not found` messages; e.g., `endX`, `endY`, etc. You can have a look at [the `R.attr` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#endX) to see that they were introduced in API level 24.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with the XML file. On the line number the logcat must be returning, if all the above steps failed. That means there must be a error in the declared attribute of that particular component.